# Spring @Transcational and "failed to lazily initialize a collection"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, service

Service class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MovieServiceImpl implements MovieService {

    @Override
    public void refreshAverageRating(Movie movie) throws DataAccessException {
        movieRepository.refreshAverageRating(movie);
    }

    @Override
    public void refreshAverageRating(Collection<Movie> movies) throws DataAccessException {
        for (Movie movie : movies){
            refreshAverageRating(movie);
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public class MovieRepositoryImpl implements MovieRepository {
    @Override
    public void refreshAverageRating(Movie movie) throws DataAccessException {
        .....
        List<Rating> ratings = movie.getRatings(); ///fails here
        .....
    }
}
```

I can't understand why I get an Exception. I thought `@Transactional` should provide the session.

And yes, I understand what is `fetchType.LAZY` and will not change it to `EAGER`.

Comment: Post your Spring config.

Comment: What's your session scope? The session that you loaded `Movie` in is likely closed. Opening a new, unrelated, session isn't going to help that.

Comment: @Tunaki https://github.com/SerhiiKryvokin/imdb/tree/master/src/main/java/com/imdb/config

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes, `Movie` was returned from another method of service, so the session that loaded it is closed, right? How to deal with it then? Attach `Movie` to current session?

Comment: @Sloth I wouldn't try and reattach objects - it's slow and messy. I would keep your session open through your unit of work unless you have good reason not to. `@Transactional` can be added to the widest scope - that will work. Otherwise, in a web app, you can use the open session in view pattern.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have one question more. If I declared `@Transactional` on class, what will happen when one method from this class calls another one?

Comment: @Sloth It depends on the transaction propagation. By default it is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED which means the inner method comes under the same physical transaction as the outer method.

Comment: Annotate your `RootConfig` with `@Import(RepositoryConfing.java)`. I'm not sure thtat configuration is loaded by Spring

Comment: @FrancescoPitzalis I'm sure.